# max-height div and in div and paragraph in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.wrap
{
  
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }

.content
{
  width:300px;
  max-height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:50px;
  }
.content p
{
  margin:0;
  }
.header
{
  margin-left:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
    height:20px;
   }
.header p
{
  margin:0;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    
    
  </div>
  
  
 </div>
```

Hello,
I have question about CSS only I think, maybe JS will be necessary. I would like that paragraph

was always in div (blue), and blue div will never exceed beyond div class="wrap". When if add more text in header blue div decrease height.

Comment: add into `content` two more css :  `overflow:hidden; overflow-y:auto;` but, you need to decrease `height` for `content` ... you can, also, use `overflow` for `wrap`, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `max-height:180px;` and add `overflow: hidden` for `.content`

```css
.wrap
{
  
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }

.content
{
  width:300px;
  max-height:180px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
.content p
{
  margin:0;
  }
.header
{
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
    height:20px;
   }
.header p
{
  margin:0;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    
    
  </div>
  
  
 </div>
```

Comment: where is last words ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
    width:300px;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

Replace `max-height` in `.content` with `min-height` to automatically increase the height of the `.content` if the content inside it goes beyond its minimum height of `200px`.

Add `overflow-y: auto` rule to `.wrap`. This will apply scroll bar to `.wrap` only if the content inside it goes beyond its height defined which is `200px` or you can set `scroll` explicitly to the property to apply the scroll bar regardless of height of the content inside it goes beyond the defined.

```css
.wrap {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.content p {
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
}

.header p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="header">
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can also apply scroll bar to `.content` alone rather than applying it to `.wrap`. This would only make the `.content` scrollable.

```
.wrap {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    width:300px;
    max-height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left:50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This styling makes the `.content` scrollable if the defined height exceeds. `.wrap` height stays the same with the `overflow: hidden` which means you can't scroll it despite the height of the content inside it is whatever.

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xs24gfuk/)?

> CSS

```
.content
{
  width:300px;
  max-height:175px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
  }
```